# Pass a Lookup<TKey, TElement> to a repeater and then access the dataItem

Tags: c#, linq, repeater

I have a List of Blogs and I wanted to group them by Year

```
var data = Controller.Blog.GetBlogs().GroupBy(x => x.Year);
```

After I group I need to bind the data to a repeater to read the year and then bind the 
the content to a nested repeater
I use

```
var data = e.Item.DataItem;
```

but I dont know what to cast to. I tried a lot of options but nothing was working.
I might be tackling the problem in a wrong way, so if I am, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think you have to provide more code to show what you want to acheive and what is not working for you.

Comment: I totally forgot about this question. I think what I have to do is say var data = e.Item.DataItem as IGrouping<int, Blog>.